# How can I use global declared object in Nestjs?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

```
// src/types/format.ts
const ImageFormat = {
  JPG: 'jpg',
  JPEG: 'jpeg',
  PNG: 'png',
  GIF: 'gif',
  BMP: 'bmp',
} as const;
type ImageFormat = typeof ImageFormat[keyof typeof ImageFormat];
```

I have types declared in global scope like above.

When I use ImageFormat as a type inside any Nestjs modules, this works fine. However, when I try to use it as a object, it is undefined.

For example, something like this

```
@Injectable()
export class ImageService {
  isImageFormat(format: string): format is ImageFormat {
    return Object.values(ImageFormat).includes(format as ImageFormat);
  }
}
```

or like this,

```
export const isImageFormat = (format: string): format is ImageFormat => {
  return Object.values(ImageFormat).includes(format as ImageFormat);
};
```

will all cause a runtime error, saying ImageFormat is undefined.

From here, I had two options.

1. use ConfigService just like using env
2. export it

I didn't want to use ConfigService as this would get too much verbose and will have to add to ConfigService everytime I make new readonly objects or enums in type files.

So, exporting it from elsewhere did work with a bit problem.

```
// /util/format.ts
export const ImageFormat = {
  JPG: 'jpg',
  JPEG: 'jpeg',
  PNG: 'png',
  GIF: 'gif',
  BMP: 'bmp',
} as const;
export type ImageFormat = typeof ImageFormat[keyof typeof ImageFormat];
export const isImageFormat = (format: string): format is ImageFormat => {
  return Object.values(ImageFormat).includes(format as ImageFormat);
};
```

now I can't use ImageFormat as a type globally and have to import before usage. Well, I can make another file which is not a module and declare the type globally, but this ends up duplicating code.

```
// /types/format.ts
const ImageFormat = {
  JPG: 'jpg',
  JPEG: 'jpeg',
  PNG: 'png',
  GIF: 'gif',
  BMP: 'bmp',
} as const;
type ImageFormat = typeof ImageFormat[keyof typeof ImageFormat];
```

Would there be any magical solution of using a global scoped object in Nestjs?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way.

Here's how.

```
// /types/file.ts
export const ImageFormat = {
  JPG: 'jpg',
  JPEG: 'jpeg',
  PNG: 'png',
  GIF: 'gif',
  BMP: 'bmp',
} as const;
declare global {
  type ImageFormat = typeof ImageFormat[keyof typeof ImageFormat];
}
export const isImageFormat = (format: string): format is ImageFormat => {
  return Object.values(ImageFormat).includes(format as ImageFormat);
};
```

You can declare global scope from a module.